# protobuf: clang frontend command failed with exit code 70 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: xcode, clang, cocoapods, protocol-buffers

Recently I removed `Fabric` from project and installed `Firebase/Crashlytics` instead. After that when I try to upload app to AppStore using `fastlane` or do it using native Xcode tools I faced with such error:

```
Clang frontend command failed with exit code 70 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[image]

I've tried to clean DerivedData folder, `pod deintegrate`, `pod install` but error remains.

List of pods:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Locksmith'
pod 'CryptoSwift'
pod 'QRCode'
pod 'MessageKit'
pod 'MessageInputBar'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 5.0.0-beta.3'
pod 'SQLite.swift', '~> 0.12.0'
pod 'ReachabilitySwift'
pod 'Localize-Swift', '~> 2.0'
```

Version of Xcode - `10.1 (10B61)`

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm also getting this same issue. Please let me know if you find any solution of this. Thanks

Comment: Below pod combinations works for me,

pod 'Firebase/Core','~> 6.0.0'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Protobuf','~> 3.5.0'

Comment: @RahulBansal as Paul Beusterien mentioned below it is because of Xcode version. So in my case I decided to update my macbook pro from early 2011 to 2019 with Catalina and Xcode 11.5 :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current version of Firebase require at least Xcode 10.3. Details at https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup

Comment: Thanks Paul. By any chance could you please suggest from where I can find the version of Firebase suitable for Xcode 10.1

Comment: Versions before 6.16.0 supported Xcode 10.1 - See https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after removing Fabric and Crashlytics from my Podfile (Protobuf error). I simply put both back into my Podfile and the error when away in Xcode and I was able to archive my iOS project. The version of Protobuf went from 3.12.0 to 3.7.0 in my Podfile.lock. Xcode Version 10.1 (10B61) on MacOS 10.14 Mojave.

UPDATE - Protobuf 3.12.0 on Xcode 11.5 (11E608c) on MacOS 10.15.4 seems fine. I was able to remove Fabric and Crashlytics.